# Can you keep blocks clutched together in big chunks? Will blocks loose their "clutch power" after years of that kind of keeping?

Tags: storage

I keep my blocks of same type in big assembled chunks, for easy building and finding bricks, but I am worried, is it safe for them or will they tend to lose strength in some time (years maybe)?

Comment: How did I miss that duplicate?! Sorry.